# not able to telnet or curl <node-ip>:<node-port> kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, service-node-port-range

Not able to telnet or curl :

```
discovery-server       NodePort       10.109.29.219    34.0.0.96   8761:31792/TCP   20d

telnet 34.0.0.96:31792 does not return anything 
curl http://34.0.0.96:31792 does not return anything
```

if I enter the container and `curl http://localhost:8761` then it's working fine

what could be the issue

all ports are open in security group.

Comment: does the curl return any error? Where are you giving the curl to localhost from? master or worker? can you give more details about your cluster. I recently faced a similar issue which turned out to be regarding the kubedns.

Comment: May be your app is serving on localhost. Try serving on `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: 34.0.0.96 is it loadBalancer IP?
did you executed the *curl http://localhost:8761* inside of pod? first you need to check for networking.

try to get the host IP on which your pod is currently running and then try to make curl or telnet to that IP with 31792 port. if that works, then check for the loadBalancer/Endpoint configuration.

Comment: 34.0.0.96 is a external Ip (master node IP ) which I have patched with this svc . yes I have tried curl localhost:8761 from inside the pod and its working fine . But when I do the same from any node curl <external-ip>:<node-ip> it does not work or return anything

Comment: As you said all ports are open through sg. So, can you try `curl localhost:31792` on that particular node and see what's the output you are receiving? And also try `curl 10.109.29.219:8761` on the same node and see what you are receiving? If both turned out to be working then there is no problem with the svc or something is around svc. If any of them don't work, could you provide details about svc, it would be easy to debug.